# Collecting Data From a Pressed DOM created Button

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create a sort of deck creator in JS, I have the prototype, but I want to make it a bit more modular. So I made a else loop to create DOM buttons. The problem I'm having is I can't seem to figure out how to get the id/any number from the SPECIFIC button I pressed.

```
var cardName = ["Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3", "Card 4", "Card 5", "Card 6"]
var Card;
var isInDeck = ["false", "false", "false", "false", "false"];
var Deck = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cardName.length; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = cardName[i];
  button.classList = "Button";
  button.setAttribute('id', cardName[i]);
  document.getElementById("buttonPlace").appendChild(button);
}
```

EDIT, I have already tried adding

```
button.onClick = function () {Card = i;}
```

after it in the for loop, and it didn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an eventlistener to the button. With that you can get all the data your button currently holds

```
for (var i = 0; i < cardName.length; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");

  ... // your button setup

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(this); // this is your button element
      console.log(this.id); // this is the ID you assigned with "setAttribute"
  });

  document.getElementById("buttonPlace").appendChild(button);
}
```

This way you can access any data you assigned to the button beforehand. In the callback function for `click` you can then do further stuff with your data.

If you don't want to have an anonymous function inside your loop, you can seperate it like following:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(this); // this is your button element
    console.log(this.id); // this is the ID you assigned with "setAttribute"
}

for (var i = 0; i < cardName.length; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");

  ... // your button setup

  button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

  document.getElementById("buttonPlace").appendChild(button);
}
```

Look on [mozilla.org for more on eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Lol other than the ```console.log(this);``` destroyed my console, it works perfectly, and thank you I did not know that Event Listeners were so good

Comment: Quick question, does it have to be inside the for loop? And it is giving me the warning of May Cause Confusing Semantics, will this cause any problems or is it just an odd warning

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent The addEventListener has to be inside the loop, because you don't have access to your buttons from outside (as long as you don't save them to any variable). But you can seperate the callback function, for this I've updated the answer with a second example. Hope this helps keeping your code clean :)